# linq-to-entity dynamic queries

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'am currently migrating our old system to .Net and I encountered this problem.
I want to return the result but I still need to refine it after the function, but using this code, I don't have a choice but to call the result from the database and filter an in-memory result instead which is poor performance.

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUser(string[] accessCodes)
{
    string condition = "";
    if (accessCodes == null)
    {
         condition = " AccessCode IS NOT NULL "
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= accessCodes.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            condition += " AccessCode LIKE '%" + accessCodes[i].ToString() + "%' ";
            if (i + 1 <= code.Length - 1)
            {
                condition += " OR ";
            }
        }
    }

    return context.ExecuteQuery<User>("SELECT * FROM User WHERE " + condition, null).ToList();
}
```

I've tried this approach this but i'm stuck:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUser(string[] accessCodes)
{
    IQueryable<User> basequery = from u in context.User 
                                 select u;

    if (accessCodes == null)
    {
         basequery = basequery.Where(n => n.AccessCode != null);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= accessCodes.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            // what am I supposed to do here?
        }
    }

    return basequery;
}
```

I'm hoping that there are solutions which do not require third party libraries.

Comment: Could you please explain in simple terms what you are trying to achieve? you want to filter users based on what criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `Any`:

```
else
{
    output = output.Where(u => accessCodes.Any(a => u.AccessCode.Contains(a)));
}
```

or you can use [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx):

```
if (accessCodes == null)
{
    output = output.Where(u => u.AccessCode == null);
}
else
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<User>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= accessCodes.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or(u => u.AccessCode.Contains(accessCodes[i]))
    }

    output = output.Where(predicate);
}
```

I also changed your `if` part: `Where` method does not modify source, it returns new query definition, so you have to assign it back to `output` to make it work.

Comment: Hi, Marcin, when I used the ".Any" it throws an exception "DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.".

I've tried using the predicate builder directly and it also throws an error "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported". I've read the PredicateBuilder instruction that in order to use PredicateBuilder in entity framework I need to use the "LINQKit.dll". Is there any work around without using the LINQKit.dll?

Comment: Hi again, never mind, .Any() is sufficient, it seems that I've been using char[] instead of string[] which causes the exception.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
IQueryable<User> basequery = from u in context.User 
                             select u;
if (accessCodes == null)
{
    basequery = basequery.Where(u => u.AccessCode != null);
}
else
{
    basequery = basequery.Where(u => accessCodes.Contains(u=>u.AccessCode));
}
```

also make sure you return `basequery`, since `output` in your method is not defined and not used.

Comment: this will work if there is only one access code, but as what I've posted above, sometimes it requires more than one access code that is why it's inside a loop.

Comment: accessCodes.Contains(u=>u.AccessCode) it will produce what you need. `Contains` iterates through codes and linq handles that correctly. Check the output query using your `ToTraceString()` method.

Comment: .Contains is not sufficient, let say the accessCode is only composed of the string "m", it must retrieve "m", "mx", "m3", "mp" and not "m' only.

Comment: sorry, I thought about searching for access codes present in the list.